# SSRS - report location

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS - I deployed a report a while back and can't find it. I need to find it so I can download it. How do I find out what folder it is on the SSRS report server? I know the report name and which SSRS server it is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on the ReportServer database.

```
Select Name, Path
From Catalog c
Where Type = 2
AND Name like '%whatever%'
```